# Hibernate EntityManager is not injected to Stateless EJB

Tags: hibernate, jpa, dependency-injection, java-ee-6, hibernate-entitymanager

this was asked a lot of times I guess, but I just cant seem to get it right.
I have a WAR application deployed on Webpshere 8.5.5.9 with some EJB components and trying to use JPA 2.0 and Hibernate 4.2.0 to do database work.
These EJBs are called from other applications through JNDI to request data from database.
I generated Stubs for the client side and all works (well... almost since I wouldn't post the question :) :

Client calls remote interface IDatabaseService through JNDI and the container returns DBServiceBean as implementation

```
@Stateless
@Remote({ IDatabaseService.class })
public class DBServiceBean implements IDatabaseService
{
    @EJB
    private ApplicationService applicationService;

    @Override
    public BOApplication getApplication(String applicationId)
    {
        BOApplication app = applicationService.getApplication(applicationId);
        return app;
    }

    // getters and setters
}
```

DBServiceBean has a service injected as EJB

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class ApplicationServiceImpl implements ApplicationService
{
    @EJB
    private ApplicationDao applicationDao;

    @Override
    public BOApplication getApplication(String applicationId)
    {
        DBApplication dbApplication = applicationDao.getApplication(applicationId);

        BOApplication application = new BOApplication(dbApplication);
        return application;
    }

    // getters and setters
}
```

ApplicationService has a DAO property injected as EJB

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class HBApplicationDao implements ApplicationDao
{
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "some.jpa.name")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public DBApplication getApplication(String applicationId)
    {
        String sql = "....";
        Query query = em.createQuery(sql, DBApplication.class);
        query.setParameter("applicationid", applicationId);
        DBApplication application = (DBApplication) query.getSingleResult();

        return application;
    }

    public void setEm(EntityManager em)
    {
        this.em = em;
    }
}
```

The DAO has and entity manager.
Everything works fine and all components get injected OK but the Entity manager injection doesn't happen and entity manager is NULL in runtime

When I check the logs all classes, binding, hibernate mappings etc are created with no issues but I never see the entity manager setter being called when i put a log message inside.

Here is my persistence.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="some.jpa.name" transaction-type="JTA">  
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/ExtensionDB</jta-data-source>
        <class>some.package.entity.DBApplication</class>
        <class>some.package.entity.DBApplicant</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
            <property name="openjpa.TransactionMode" value="managed" />
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionFactoryMode" value="managed" />
            <property name="openjpa.jdbc.DBDictionary" value="oracle" />
        </properties> 
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I understand the entity manager is not injected on bean creation but after that bean its injected somewhere. Also that bean must be injected in another container-managed object (like JSF bean as example)
I read topics about this issue but I am not sure what requirement I did not met

Thank you in advance for any tips or pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry, the issue was not that entity manager was null but em.createQuery() threw a NullpointerException.

After googling soome similar problems, I found out that my persistence.xml was missing a needed property

```
<property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.WebSphereExtendedJtaPlatform" />
```

after I added the property, everything worked ok.

Also these below mentioned properties were not needed (or even may cause problems). I didn't study what they do but will check them.

```
<property name="openjpa.TransactionMode" value="managed" />
<property name="openjpa.ConnectionFactoryMode" value="managed" />
<property name="openjpa.jdbc.DBDictionary" value="oracle" />
```